# aiohttp response.write buffer size

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

Is there any way to set the output buffer size of aiohttp?

I'm trying to use a streamed response like this, and the buffer size seems to be quite larger before it starts displaying anything to the client:

```
response = aiohttp.web.StreamResponse(
    status=200,
    reason='OK',
    headers=response_headers,
)
await response.write(bytes)
```

This page mentions a default 64k write buffer size, but I don't see anywhere to change it:
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html

Comment: were you able to figure this out (for request or response)?

Comment: I think in my case the larger buffer size was coming from the server in front of aiohttp. After switching to Gunicorn, it looks like it's using a 4096 byte buffer